# How to track Affiliate links in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I Have some affiliate links( from shopping site) in my magento site( magento Version 1.9). i need to track that links. Is any possible way to track affiliate links. i have no idea about that please help me.

Answer (score 1):

[This Should Help You](http://www.magestore.com/affiliateplus/features.html/)

Look at **Banner & Link management** In this Link to Know How to track Affiliate Links In Magento

Comment: Thank you sir for your help.... without extension is any possible way to code ??? @hariharan